# Rails polymorphic comments dumping object in view - how do I stop this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, comments

I am learning Rails and recently implemented comments as a polymophic association.  Everything works fine except along with the comments being rendered in my view I am also getting the raw object code dumped into the view and rendering below the comments.
I have spent hours trying to find the solution but cannot.  Is there ayone out there that can help or point me in the right direction?
Ruby version: 2.3.1p112, Rails version: 5.1.4 Chromium:  63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Screenshot:
[screenshot of view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Oz7.png)

Thanks!

Models:

/app/models/pin.rb

```
class Pin < ApplicationRecord
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>" }, 
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: 
    /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

/app/models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Controllers:

/app/controllers/pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @pin = current_user.pins.build
    end

    def create
        @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

        if @pin.save
            redirect_to @pin, notice: "Successfully created new Pin."
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @pin.update(pin_params)
            redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin was Successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @pin.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def upvote
        @pin.upvote_by current_user
        redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
    end


    private

    def pin_params
        params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image)
    end

    def find_pin
        @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params
        @comment.user = current_user
        @comment.save
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Your comment was successfully posted."
    end


    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end

end
```

/app/controllers/pins/comments_controller.rb

```
class Pins::CommentsController < CommentsController
    before_action :set_commentable

    private
        def set_commentable
            @commentable = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
        end


end
```

Views:

/app/views/show.html.haml

```
#pin_show.row
    .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
        .panel.panel-default
            .panel-heading.pin_image
                =image_tag @pin.image.url
            .panel-body
                %h1= @pin.title
                %p.description= @pin.description

                = render partial: "comments/comments" , locals: {commentable: @pin} 
                = render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @pin}

            .panel-footer
                .row
                    .col-md-6
                        %p.user
                        Pin submitted by
                        = @pin.user.email
                    .col-md-6
                        .btn-group.pull-right
                            = link_to like_pin_path(@pin), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do
                                %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
                                    = @pin.get_upvotes.size
                            - if user_signed_in?
                                = link_to "Edit", edit_pin_path, class: "btn btn-default"
                                %button.btn.btn-danger{"data-target" => "#exampleModal#{@pin.id}", "data-toggle" => "modal", type: "button"} Delete

                                =render 'modal'
```

app/view/comments/_comments.html.haml:

```
#Comments
    %h4 Comments..
    = @pin.comments.each do |comment|   #- problem here
        .well
            = comment.body
```

Routes:

/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  resources :pins do
    member do
        put "like", to: "pins#upvote"
    end
    resources :comments, module: :pins
  end


  root "pins#index"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are getting a raw object because you are using `=` in your iteration block which will display the `@pin.comments` object. Changing

```
= @pin.comments.each do |comment|
```

to

```
- @pin.comments.each do |comment|
```

will do the trick. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Anees!  Unbelievable such a simple thing.

Comment: @DarrellMayson Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

modify following code

```
#Comments
    %h4 Comments..
    = @pin.comments.each do |comment|   #- problem here
        .well
            = comment.body
```

as

```
#Comments
    %h4 Comments..
    - @pin.comments.each do |comment|
        .well
            = comment.body
```

you are using haml template engine so, An equals sign, `=`, will output the result of the code. A hyphen, `-`, will run the code but not output the result.